# Python - create mock test for class method that has context manager

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, patch, with-statement

I'm trying to write a unit test for a method of a class that has a context manager and many calls. I'm having a difficulty time understanding how to properly mock the function so that I can test the return value.
The class I am trying to mock is db. As you can see below I'm using a patch, but I'm not able to figure out how to get it to return the correct method call. I'm getting a generic mock function instead of the return value I expect.

db_class.py

```
import db

class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def method(self):
        with db.a() as a:
            b = a.b
            return b.fetch()
```

unit_db.py

```
 from mock import Mock, patch, MagicMock
 from db_class import Foo

 @patch('db_class.db')
 def test(db_mock):
     expected_result = [5,10]
     db_mock.return_value = Mock(__enter__ = db_mock,
                                 __exit___ = Mock(),
                                 b = Mock(fetch=expected_result))
 
     foo = Foo()
     result = foo.method()
     assert result == expected_result
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to mock?

Comment: Could you please check your code? Foo is not part of db, but db_class according to what you wrote. It also seems that you are trying to mock the whole db module, but inside your with statement what you need is to mock the db.a() method. Finally, you misunderstood how to specify methods in a mock. Here __enter__ and __exit__ are attributes but should be methods. Same for fetch in the spec of b.

Comment: @Cilyan - Thanks for the response - I updated the code to have the Foo method imported correctly  Your response makes a lot of sense, I'm guessing first I should add another patch @patch('db_class.db.a') to be mocked. I'm am still confused on how to implement fetch, __enter__ and __exit__ as methods  vs attributes.

Comment: @vks I'm trying to mock the db_class foo.method. I want to check that the result that it returns is the expected result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to the commenters I have found a solution that works for me. The trick was to patch the correct class, in this case I wanted to patch db_class.db.a instead of db_class.db. After that, it is important to make sure that the fetch() call is a method (I think I'm getting that correct). The tricky part about this problem for me was patching the correct thing as well as dealing with the context manager which requires a bit of extra tinkering.

```
@patch('db_class.db.a')
def test(db_a):
    expected_result = [5,10]
    b_fetch = MagicMock()
    b_fetch.fetch.return_value = expected_result 
    db_a.return_value = Mock(b = b_fetch,
                         __enter__= db_a,
                         __exit__ =Mock())
    foo = Foo()
    result = foo.method()
    assert result == expected_result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```

Comment: Nice approach with your context mocking.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the same test, using pytest and [mocker fixture](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-mock/):

```
def test(mocker):
    mock_db = mocker.MagicMock(name='db')
    mocker.patch('db_class.db', new=mock_db)
    expected_result = [5, 10]
    mock_db.a.return_value.__enter__.return_value.b.fetch.return_value = expected_result

    foo = db_class.Foo()
    result = foo.method()
    assert result == expected_result
```

You may find the way I wrote the test more interesting than the test itself - I have created a [python library](https://pypi.org/project/mock-generator/) to help me with the syntax.

Here is how I approached your problem in a systematic way:

We start with the test you want and my helper library:

```
import db_class

from mock_autogen.pytest_mocker import PytestMocker

def test(mocker):
    # this would output the mocks we need
    print(PytestMocker(db_class).mock_modules().prepare_asserts_calls().generate())

    # your original test, without the mocks
    expected_result = [5,10]
    foo = db_class.Foo()
    result = foo.method()
    assert result == expected_result
```

Now the test obviously fails (`AttributeError: module 'db' has no attribute 'a'`), but the print output is useful:

```
# mocked modules
mock_db = mocker.MagicMock(name='db')
mocker.patch('db_class.db', new=mock_db)
# calls to generate_asserts, put this after the 'act'
import mock_autogen
print(mock_autogen.generator.generate_asserts(mock_db, name='mock_db'))
```

Now, I'm placing the mocks before the call to `Foo()` and the `generate_asserts` after, just before your assert, like so (no need for the previous print, so I removed it):

```
def test(mocker):
    # mocked modules
    mock_db = mocker.MagicMock(name='db')
    mocker.patch('db_class.db', new=mock_db)

    # your original test, without the mocks
    expected_result = [5,10]
    foo = db_class.Foo()
    result = foo.method()

    # calls to generate_asserts, put this after the 'act'
    import mock_autogen
    print(mock_autogen.generator.generate_asserts(mock_db, name='mock_db'))

    assert result == expected_result
```

Now the assert fails (`AssertionError: assert <MagicMock name='db.a().__enter__().b.fetch()' id='139996983259768'> == [5, 10]`), but we have once more gained some valuable input:

```
mock_db.a.return_value.__enter__.assert_called_once_with()
mock_db.a.return_value.__enter__.return_value.b.fetch.assert_called_once_with()
mock_db.a.return_value.__exit__.assert_called_once_with(None, None, None)
```

Notice the second line, it's almost what you need to mock. With a slight alteration it would look like `mock_db.a.return_value.__enter__.return_value.b.fetch.return_value = expected_result`, and with that, we can have the final version of the test:

```
def test(mocker):
    mock_db = mocker.MagicMock(name='db')
    mocker.patch('db_class.db', new=mock_db)
    expected_result = [5, 10]
    mock_db.a.return_value.__enter__.return_value.b.fetch.return_value = expected_result

    foo = db_class.Foo()
    result = foo.method()
    assert result == expected_result
```

You may add the additional automatically generated asserts, or alter them to include additional asserts if you find that useful.